# Extracting some values from JSON objects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON text (posted below) and I want to extract `name` and `channel_remote_number` from each of its object inside its `item` array. Can someone please guide how can I do that?

**JSON Text:**

```
{  
   "xml":{  
      "version":"3.0.0",
      "item_startidx":"0",
      "total_items":"471",
      "items_link":"https://example_url/",
      "items":{  
         "item":[  
            {  
               "id":"36438",
               "name":"A plus",
               "type":"liveWMV",
               "link":"https://example_url/",
               "duration":"35000",
               "channel_logo":{  
                  "#cdata":"http://example_url/"
               },
               "channel_remote_number":"180",
               "description":"A plus",
               "response_link":"https://example_url/",
               "restrict_link":"https://example_url/",
               "play_time":"https://example_url/",
               "protected":"no",
               "program_listing":"https://example_url/",
               "program_guide":"https://example_url/",
               "electronic_program_guide":"https://example_url/",
               "catchup_tv":"7",
               "popup":{  
                  "type":"blocking",
                  "message":"Temporary Down",
                  "buttons":{  
                     "button":{  
                        "type":"cancel",
                        "text":"OK"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "category_id":"12797",
               "path":"Smart TV App&gt;Live TV&gt;Pakistani&gt;Entertainment"
            },
            {  
               "id":"37669",
               "name":"A plus",
               "type":"liveWMV",
               "link":"https://example_url/",
               "duration":"35000",
               "channel_logo":{  
                  "#cdata":"http://example_url/"
               },
               "channel_remote_number":"180",
               "description":"A plus",
               "response_link":"https://example_url/",
               "restrict_link":"https://example_url/",
               "play_time":"https://example_url/",
               "protected":"no",
               "program_listing":"https://example_url/",
               "program_guide":"https://example_url/",
               "electronic_program_guide":"https://example_url/",
               "catchup_tv":"7",
               "popup":{  
                  "type":"blocking",
                  "message":"Temporary Down",
                  "buttons":{  
                     "button":{  
                        "type":"cancel",
                        "text":"OK"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "category_id":"12797",
               "path":"Smart TV App&gt;Live TV&gt;Pakistani&gt;Entertainment"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {  
              "xml": {....

var answer = data.xml.items.item
      .map(x => ({ name: x.name, channel_remote_number: x.channel_remote_number }));
```